# Audio buzz and video glitch when any update or restore point creation starts the Volume Shadow Service

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, audio, 64-bit, vss

I have the above problem and see that others do too.  I've had no help from Microsoft and am asking if anyone else knows a solution.  Please post if you do.

Here is a description of the problem, what troubleshooting has been done, and what has been learned:

It's pursued me through two computers and 3 hard drives, and troubleshooting has eliminated every program and attached device. In searching the NET I've found the problem is shared by many, who discuss it in relation to just about every product out there. Gamers think it must be because of their game. Carbonite users think it must be because of their Carbonite. Builders think it must be because they put the wrong USB drive in. etc.

But after 13 months of troubleshooting all evidence points to A WINDOWS PROBLEM.

I've found I can even provoke the event simply by creating a restore point. The audio/video aberration will occur about 5 seconds after you push "create." Event logs won't log anything at EXACTLY that moment, but you will see about 35 seconds after you push "create" that the Volume Shadow Service will show an 8220 "ran out of time while deleting files" error.

As for when the event occurs "naturally" whenever any program tries to make a shadow copy in order to install an update, for instance, these events will show up after the logs show an automatic update invoking the volume shadow copy service and creating a restore point.

I tried to post a photo of what the disk write error spikes look like in Resource Monitor, but SuperUser won't allow it. So I will describe it. If you provoke such an event while running the Resource Monitor, you will see a huge hard-fault spike on the Memory graph associated with about 30+ seconds of full-capacity spiking on the Disk graph. On the Disk screen you'll see huge numbers for the Disk processes System 4 and VSSVC.exe, with the VSSVC.exe numbers going down sharply as soon as the Disk spike abates on the graph.

Though the company from which I bought my computer has valiantly given me 2 replacements (shout out to Dell for that) it looks now like there isn't much hope of solving it through new computers. And I see from others' experience that MicroSoft still maintains that this is normal and harmless.

After losing 2 systems that either became unable to update after the problem permanently corrupted their update processes, or in one case that just plain crashed to the point of unfixability, I do not think this is harmless.

At the very least, I hope that in posting this I will save others the trouble of following false leads.

But if you are technically savvy and can offer a solution, please share!

Thank you.

Comment: I have asked for help in finding a solution, and I have offered 13 months of troubleshooting information which may save others in the same situation (of which the Internet reveals many) from pursuing fruitless avenues of investigation.

Comment: Just deleted my un-useful comment. You have a valid issue. I highly doubt there's going to be a silver-bullet answer because, if there was, you would have found it after 13 months. Still, fingers crossed, someone here may be able to help.

Comment: Thank you, Misha.  Yes, my fingers are crossed too.